# iOS custom UIViewController container - view lifecycle and dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have written a custom view controller container that can replace the existing view controller (VC1) with a new view controller(VC2) i.e. a replace type segue rather than pop/push.

Everything worked fine until testing with iOS 8. It seems a second party I'm using causes a crash if the view controller is replaced before the previous view controller is dealloc

i.e. if [VC2 viewDidLoad] called before [VC1 dealloc].

It is my understanding that I have no control over the dealloc so this kind of behaviour is out of my control. However, I want to make sure that I am not causing this behaviour in the way I'm controlling my child view controllers.

The following is pseudo code for my view controller container:

```
- (void)replaceStackWithNewController:(UIViewController*)newVC {

for(UIViewController *vc in [self viewControllers]) {
  [vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
  if([vc isViewLoaded]
     [[vc view] removeFromSuperview];
  }
  [vc removeFromParentViewController];
}
//self.viewControllers is my navigation stack
self.viewControllers = nil;
self.childVC = nil;

if(newVC != nil) {
  self.childVC = newVC;
}

[self addChildViewController:newVC];
//this adds the view to a pre existing wrapper
[self addView:newVC.view ToWrapper:wrapper];
//add controller to stack
[self.viewControllers addObject:newVC];
[newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```